# Applying custom css to button in peoplesoft

Tags: css, peoplesoft, peoplecode

I'm new to PeopleSoft and Application Designer.  I'm working on Peoplesoft 9.0. I want to create a custom button appearance with a custom CSS style.

- I added a button to a page.
- I created a Style Sheet with Type (Free Form Style-sheet) with the following script and saved it with the name "Design":

> ```
> .button1  {    
>  background-color:#FFF0F5;
>                  color: black;
>                  padding: 8px 32px;
>                  text-align: center;
>                  display: inline-block;
>                   font-size: 16px;
>                   margin: 4px 2px;
>                  cursor: pointer; 
>                 -moz-border-radius: 7px;
>                 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;}
> ```

- In the Component's PostBuild PeopleCode event, I added the following line:

> ```
> AddStyleSheet(StyleSheet.DESIGN);
> ```

But when I double-click on one of the buttons to add the style on it, in the Type tab and style field I can't find the custom style I created named "Design".

I tried to add (button1 - .button1 - # button1) in the Fluid tab and Default Style Name.

I also added this CSS in the branding in the PeopleSoft application via the PIA.

But nothing works and the button uses the default style.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but can you also share what version of PeopleTools are you on? It may be helpful to others.

Comment: I'm using 8.54.

Answer (score 0):

It seems page style only displays default or override class styles. 
Do a Save As of default style sheet, override any classes you want, update the page style sheet name to newly created style sheet, system will display the properties you updated.
we can also create new classes, and only able to assign it through  People code.

Answer (score 0):

Button Styles will be shown according to the style associated with the page. Also, it will only display style classes, Make sure you have a style class with name button in your custom created style sheet. In free form style sheet you can apply CSS to the elements.